# -ms-grid sub child rules

Tags: css, html, grid

I've got following html structure:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="sub-child-1"></div>
    <div class="sub-child-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and following css rules

```
.parent {
  display: -ms-grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 150px 1fr 1fr;
}
.child {
  -ms-grid-column-span: 2;
}
```

How can I assign `sub-child-1` to first column and `sub-child-2` to second one?

Comment: Could you provide a less simplified example so I can figure out what you're trying to achieve and possibly offer a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Considering this works in IE (can't test, I'm on linux) it should be:

```
.sub-child-1 {
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
}

.sub-child-2 {
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 2;
}
```

I'm pretty sure you have to move the sub-child-1 and sub-child-2 to the parent though, or define a grid on the child instead of the parent.